# Can GNU tar run a filter before adding a file to an archive?

Tags: tar, split

I am trying to archive a directory containing many subdirectories and files, most of which are JPEG files. I would like to run each file through [JPEG XL](https://gitlab.com/wg1/jpeg-xl) before adding to the tar archive, to reduce storage requirements for the archived file.

I would like to use GNU tar as the archiver, but I cannot find any way to ask tar to run a command on each file before adding it to the archive. I'm aware of the `--to-command` option to GNU tar; I would like something that does the same but in reverse.

One solution would be to run JPEG XL on all the JPEG files as a batch preprocessing step, and then `tar` the results. However, this would generate a large volume of intermediary files to store, and I would prefer to stream the files one by one into `tar`.

I'm aware that I might be able to use `find` to match every file and directory, and pass each one to a script which does the compression and then uses `tar --append` to grow a tar archive one file at a time, but I *also* want to pipe the resultant tar file into `split`, and I think this approach would cause at least one extra pass through all the data.

Comment: The "tar" (Tape Archive) part of GNU Tar wants to create an image of a directory, including filenames. So, I don't think what you're after can be done, since the various pipes you plan to feed into `tar` won't be associated with names in some directory. What would it look like when extracting? If the reason for not wanting a preprocessing step is to avoid disk I/O and/or avoid having a bunch of superfluous files hanging around afterwards, you could consider using a tmpfs, which would solve both problems.

Comment: not to mention that pipes are just files too

Comment: This is not an answer, but this script might give you an idea.  This was the command sequence used before "cp" had the recursive option.                                                               
                                                                                                                                   #to copy an entire directory tree.

1) mkdir <TARGET DIR>

2) cd <FROM DIR>

3) tar cf - . | ( cd <TARGET DIR> ; tar xBf - )